# Qt Designer - Is it possible for QToolBar to have QToolButtons or QMenu as actions?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Is it possible to have QMenu or QToolButton as action for QToolBar in Qt Designer?

The only choice is to create actions in Action Center, then add the actions in the QToolBar.

I want with some way to have submenu's for some actions.

I know (almost) how to do this in code but i don't know how can i do this in Qt Designer.

Thanks!!

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: To extend what ekhumoro said, you can only add *real* QActions to a QToolBar in Designer, which only allows to create QMenus that are part of a QMainWindow menu bar. The only actions you can add to a toolbar in Designer are those manually created in the action editor and the **real** QActions available in the Object Inspector when created from the menu bar: as soon as you try to change an action to a submenu by adding items to it, it'll become a QMenu, you cannot add it to a toolbar anymore; if the action has already been added to a toolbar, you cannot add actions to it (to make it a submenu).